# C# application deployment: "a referral was returned from the server" error

Tags: c#, .net, deployment

I have built a c# application through visual studio. I am now trying to deploy it and send it to friends and family for testing. I have tried pulling the automatically generated executable file from the bin folder and sending that out for testing.

However, when my testers try running the executable on their own computers, they see this error: "a referral was returned from the server." The program does not even get executed. I've been scouring the web for answers. Code signing seems like a common theme, but I haven't been able to figure out a valid solution yet.

It works fine on my computer, but not on any other computers. Any thoughts as to how to get this app successfully shared / deployed? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In my scenario, I had added an application manifest because I wanted to require that the program was run with elevated privileges, because I was creating a new log source in the Windows event log. Under the node `<requestedPrivileges>`, I had put the line:

```
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="true" />
```

The `uiAccess="true"` was my problem. I innocently thought my console app needed UI access (it's a console app that a user runs, was my thought). Changing that back to false fixed my problem.

Comment: That was exact my thought as well! Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue (A referral was returned from the serve) when using:

`<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="true" />`

The issue was that `uiAccess` can be `true` only when:

- The app digitally signed.
- Must be in a secure location in the file system [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/user-account-control-only-elevate-uiaccess-applications-that-are-installed-in-secure-locations)

What you can do is:

1. Check if your application really needs `uiAccess` [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/user-account-control-only-elevate-uiaccess-applications-that-are-installed-in-secure-locations#vulnerability)
2. Sign the application

Comment: Thanks I had to set `uiAccess` to `false` to make it work

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally found an answer to this one. The issue, in my case, was not that the app needed code signing, but that we were not sending all the right files to testers along with the executable.

In the project folder, there were a lot of files (see the screenshot below). I wrongly assumed that just sending the .exe file over to other people would allow them to run the program, when in fact, the program needed to access the other files (the .dll files especially) to compile correctly.

When we finally sent all the files in the folder to testers, they were able to successfully run the app. So it seems as though the error message "a referral was returned from the server", at least in this case, meant that it couldn't find all the required components necessary for compiling and running.

[image]